# REST API Modeling tool

Tags: rest

Is there a REST API modeling tool that allows me to create the REST APIs conforming to the best practices of REST API design architecture? An in-built code generator would be helpful too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RAML](http://raml.org/) maybe your best choice. Several API design projects are open source.

- [API Designer](http://www.apihub.com/raml/api-designer)
- [API Console](http://www.apihub.com/raml-tools)
- [API Notebook](http://www.apihub.com/raml/api-notebook)

[apiary.io](http://apiary.io/) is another option, which provide API test shell(curl), API mock data and useful scripts automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's http://www.wrml.org/tools. Still they are developing this tool it might be helpful once they make it public.

Comment: This link is dead, try https://github.com/wrml/wrml